# integrating R and javascript

Tags: javascript, r, automation, web-scraping

I'm doing a  research project and I'm scraping some web data to do it.

URL: "https://demanda.ree.es/movil/peninsula/demanda/tablas/2015-09-01/1"

I use Panthom.js to make a javascript (demand.js) that:

1. take a url
2. make a "screenshot"
3. save the result in a html file (demand.html)

Now my R script execute the demand.js and read the html file that it generates to get the data I'm interested in.

My problem arises when I try to automatize the process,

To do so I have to change the URL in the javascript to get the next table from the page (as you could notice 2015-09-01 is a date).

I have to reapeat that for 2000 URLs (2000 days) more or less.

The only way I have thougth is to generate 2000 hmtl files with demand.js and read them with R, that make sense?

I dont know much about javascript, any better ideas to do it?

Please, ask if you need more information

```
// demand.js code

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'demand.html'

page.open('https://demanda.ree.es/movil/peninsula/demanda/tablas/2015-09-01/1',
function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});

## R code to load demand.html and get a vector with interesting info.
....
system("./phantomjs demand.js") 
batches <- html("demanda.html") %>%
html_nodes("#tabla_evolucion .ng-scope .ng-binding") %>% 
html_text()
....
```

Comment: Can you share relevant code?

Comment: http://mola.io/2013/08/29/unlocking-data-spain-power-generation/ might help